# No metadata for "User" was found. on NestJS with TypeOrm

Tags: sql-server, nestjs, nestjs-typeorm

I'm very new to NestJS, trying to setup a typeorm to connect with SQL Server. I get an error:

> EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "User" was found

The application run successfully but I always get the error when I try to call a `findAll()` function. Please help.

Here is my project structure:

[image]

`user.entity.ts`:

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity('tbl_users')
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn() user_id: number;

  @Column({
    name: 'Name',
    length: 255
  }) titleNameTH: string;

  @Column({
    name: 'Email',
    length: 255
  }) email: string;

  @Column({
    name: 'Active',
    type: 'bit'
  }) active: boolean;
}
```

`myhr.module.ts`:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MyhrService } from './myhr.service';
import { MyhrController } from './myhr.controller';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])],
  controllers: [MyhrController],
  providers: [MyhrService],
  exports: [MyhrService],
})
export class MyhrModule {}
```

`app.module.ts`:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(), 
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'mssql',
        host: configService.get('DB_HOST'),
        port: +configService.get('DB_PORT'),
        username: configService.get('DB_USERNAME'),
        password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
        database: configService.get('DB_DATABASE'),
        entities: [__dirname + '/../entities/**/*.entity.{js,ts}'],
        synchronize: true,
        options:  {trustServerCertificate: true} 
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }), MyhrModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`myhr.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class MyhrService {

  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private readonly userRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) { }

  async findAll() {
    return await this.userRepository.find({take:10});
  }

}
```

Comment: Looks like the issue is here: `entities: [__dirname + '/../entities/**/*.entity.{js,ts}'],` as TypeORM cannot find the entities on that path after TS transpiles. tye smething like this `entities: [ 'dist/**/**/*.entity.{js,ts}'],`

Comment: To ensure Typorm resolves all entities correctly, you can explicitly set them one by one: `entities: [User]`